# CGRect giving weird sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I am developing an iOS app and ran into a weird problem. I am doing a log of resizing of views and so on view did load, I have an ivar that holds the initial size of the view that I sized in the Interface Builder. The Initial CGFrame rect is: (x = 0, y = 63, width = 284, height = 705). The code I use to hold the initial value is:

```
filesFrame = self.fileView.frame;
```

and the only places i touch self.fileView.frame is:

```
 self.fileView.frame = filesFrame;
 self.fileView.frame = fullFilesFrame;
```

These are in two separate spots not right after each other 
fullFilesFrame is defined as:

```
fullFilesFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+63,
    self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width+63);
```

When I check my values after I resize back to the initial frame, The frame rect is now origin   CGPoint (x=0, y=63) 
CGSize (width=28, height=961)

how can this be?
This is the first time I'm dealing with resizing of views, and Im fairly new to iOS as well.

Comment: probably it's because of autoresizing masks being set up incorrectly. And are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to put this in a comment, but it's too long, so:

One trick I like in these situations is to override `setFrame:` in the class of the view I'm having trouble with, and set a break point in that overridden method.  If you do that then you can see when the frame changes and take a look at the call stack.

It's not always totally straight forward, overriding `setFrame:`.  The `frame` property can be set directly but it can *also* be derived from the view's `bounds` and `center`, so you might need to look for things setting the view's `bounds` or the view's `center` instead of the `frame`.

Also if the view has a non-identity `transform`, that will make the `frame` property behave very strangely.  If you are setting non-identity transforms on your view you should just avoid the frame property altogether.

Comment: Can autosizing set the bounds or center?

Comment: I haven't looked into it too carefully, but to be on the safe side I would assume that autosizing (and UIKit in general) *might* touch any of those properties.